# Affordability for clicking

Tags: usability, design-patterns, affordance, discovery

I'm making a screen for a charging station for a IOT device.
The screen displays charging status, and that will be a functionality initially.
Moving forward it will have more functionalities such as configuring the IOT devices.

I was wondering if having a container (box) on the representation of each device a creates affordability on whether something is clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box indeed invites the user to click, whereas without the box it looks like a simple status with no possible interaction.

To decrease user cognitive load of having to match which status correspond to which device, I would make the boxes larger to occupy the entire screen real estate, so that each box corresponds to a physical slot as much as possible.

Comment: Putting each box beside the physical slot is a great use of gestalt principles.

Comment: Do you know of any research behind on that? I want to know more theory. I need to have more science data to present to decision-makers.

Comment: Here is an article from Cognition showing that grouping by similarity (in their case color) is much faster when the elements share a border, compared to separated elements. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cognition.2018.08.006 In the case shown here, the similarity would likely be even slower.