# Show a user that no interaction is possible on a picture frame

Tags: interaction-design

I'm currently using a connected picture frame at my house. Since it has UPnP capability I'm able to tell it to search for a picturer in a DLNA share. On the other side, a script modifies the picture displaying useful things in quite real time:

- time
- weather
- tasks and chores
- agenda

Since it's a picture frame, **no interaction is possible** it just displays information (refreshed every 5 seconds or minute). But in an era of "everything is touchscreen", **how to show that touching this picture frame won't do anything**?

- Is there a visual clue instead of a "touching won't do anything" message?
- I saw a [previous question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/122184/affordability-for-clicking) about clickable boxes, I'll try to respect that but are there other options?

I know that "he makes mistake once, he won't do it again" could work but I'd avoid cleaning fingerprints on my frame everytime ;)

---

This picture frame has really no interaction possible, it just has a remote control with arrows to select previous/next picture and summon a settings menu.

It only displays a picture, not a website so there is no navigation possible (the picture is generated with [PHP's GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add code to the script: have the cursor change to a DO NOT ENTER symbol when mouse-over. You can add the CSS style on the picture frame "cursor: not-allowed" depending on if the picture frame is a DIV or an IFRAME. This can be applied to most anything (textarea, forms, images, etc).

[image]

[image]

If you cannot change the code – can you add a small, transparent icon to the top right corner of each photo? Perhaps a subtle "do not touch" icon? Try one of these that I just custom created for you :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a picture frame, it doesn't have a cursor (only a remote control with arrows for previous/next picture). That cursor icon is a good indicator, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @Goufailte. How about marking this as an answer so I can get some points?

Comment: Yeah, that icon would work, probably like a 2% - 6% opacitiy watermark